# Wrong bbox or descent with @font-face and opentype font

Tags: css, font-face, opentype

I embedded a opentype font with @font-face. Works fine, but the bbox or descent (or baseline/descent line?) is wrong on certain browsers/OSs. The problem is e.g. on a Mac the bbox is not right, that means to center the text in it's bbox I have to set a padding to the paragraph. I guess the font was created on Windows and was not tested on Linux and OS X, and the font rendering engines in these OSs work diffrently.

Any idea how to solve withs problem?

Screenshot of the font in Windows, Linux and Mac. Form top to bottom: Ubuntu Firefox 3, Chromium, Windows XP Firefox 3/Chrome, Mac OS X Safari 5/Firefox 4 Beta 8.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same happened to me and the problem was introduced when converting the font to woff, eot, etc using http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator.

The option "Fix Vertical Metrics" actually ruined the font height. Unchecking this option solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll have a look at it and see if it solves the problem.